# TFS constantly reopens files with MS Office extensions

Tags: tfs

A colleague has recently started to have a weird and annoying experience with TFS.

In all of his TFS workspaces, all the files with extensions of MS Office (such as .docx, .ppt, .dot etc - some of them not even true MS Office files) are constantly kept open for editing. Undoing them (be it through MS Visual Studio GUI, `tf undo`, or `tfpt uu`) works for a few moments only; then they are again shown as having been opened for editing.

There are fairly many such files, so this clobbers the 'Pending changes' list and provokes submission mistakes.

Observed both with and without MS Visual Studio running. Other members of the team have had no such experience.

Has anyone experienced anything of the sort? Is there a simple explanation and remedy?

**UPD**

There has been a development: a few .cs files started to show the same behavior. Disabling TFPT Explorer integration (actually, deinstalling TFPT altogether) was tried, but made no change.

A remedy was found: switch from local to server workspaces. Server workspaces seem to be immune to the problem. There's also some mitigation: Team Explorer has a tickbox called 'Show Solution Changes'.

As to the phenomenon itself, so far no progress in investigation. Aggressive virus scanning seems the most plausible theory so far; however, we cannot confirm it yet because the chap has no permission to disable the antivirus on his machine.

**UPD2**

We have had a few more observations:

It was noted that occasionally files remain open after committing. While committing a number of files, repository is successfully updated for all of them, but some remain on the 'pending changes' list.

We tried to see what happens if we forcibly delete a 'nasty' file from the disk and then get it back with `tf get /force`. This works (sole `tf get /force` without deleting doesn't), the file starts to behave normally. However, new files become 'nasty'.

We also tried to run the computer in safe mode, and then all the undos work as expected.

Comment: Can you check which process is using the file via Process Explorer when this issue occurs? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, we actually did that. We chose a file, set a filter in PX on that file and executed `tfpt uu`. We then only observed two processes addressing that file: tfpt.exe (reading and attribute setting) and the antivirus engine process (attribute reading). Just as much as one might expect. Actually, as far as I understand, opening a file for editing requires no modification of that file other than dropping the read-only flag.

Answer (score 1):

You mention there are submission mistakes. Do the file really change on disk or does only mark it as edited (without any real change) ? In the first case it might be that there is an automated process running on the machine changing the files. This can practically be any kind of job; it can be a local compressor job which compresses word document or even that the machine is infected with a macro virus which is trying to replicate. In the second case it might be an aggressive virus scanner that temporary removes macro's before they have annotated them as clean. Best way to diagnose it is using procmon from sysinternals and see what opens a write to these files.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The files don't really change: `tfpt uu` lists them as unchanged and undoes them. Both virus and antivirus versions seem doubtful because neither should bother to inform TFS about opening the files. An experiment showed that TFS does not track the files automatically - we changed a file on disk, and TFS didn't care (`tf status` showed no pending state afterwards). Moreover, there are a lot of .dot files, but they are all of Graphviz, not of MS Office; but they are opened too. Of course, we're trying to investigate with `procmon`; no result so far.

Comment: Sometime the explorer integration of the powertools can go haywire in this way, but that usually is limited to the preview function (something that the .dot shouldn't normally trigger). You could try disable that (using the change option in software) to see if that makes a difference.